# What is that dial on top of my sewing machine? What purpose does it serve?

Tags: sewing-machine

I have a Brother CS6000i sewing machine. I noticed that on the top of the machine, there is a dial that goes in slow increments, between 1 and 5.

I've tried turning the dial, and it doesn't seem to affect the operation of the machine in any way (the speed control is a completely different slider on the front). However, I've noticed that when I turn it to different extremes, my stitches seem to come out incorrectly (with loops on the front or back). I've set it to 4, which seems to provide an accurate stitch on the fabrics I've used it on.

What exactly does that dial do, and in what cases should I turn it to a different setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**That's a tension dial**, for adjusting how taut the upper thread is held while sewing; the adjustments run from 1 (least tension) to 5 (greatest tension), and allow you to adjust the pull of the upper thread against the thread coming from the bobbin. You've already observed this, by noting the loops migrating to the top (too high) or bottom (too low).

Different fabrics will often need different tensions, but there aren't really hard-and-fast rules for this. The typical process instead is to **sew a test seam using the same fabrics and check your tension**, adjusting up or down as needed until the two threads are balanced. That said, if you're machine basting or stitching a gathering seam, throwing the tension wildly off can make the basting much easier to pull and remove later, as one side will be very loose and easy to break (or pull through the loops of the other side, in the case of a gather).

Note that, while you can also adjust the bobbin tension in front-loading machines, this is rarely necessary and typically only done if something has gone wrong in the bobbin case. Most top-loading machines don't have a way to adjust the bobbin tension. Ordinarily, you'll only ever need to adjust the top thread tension.

[Threads Magazine](https://www.threadsmagazine.com/2015/10/13/how-to-achieve-ideal-sewing-machine-thread-tension) has a good illustrated write-up with information on factors other than the tension dial that may throw off your tension and necessitate additional adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like tension adjustment. The dial is in the same place as on my Bernina and the effect seems right. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.hunker.com/12365684/how-to-adjust-the-tension-on-a-brother-cs6000i-sewing-machine&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiU7pTP0ZfrAhU0t3EKHYJBAhsQFnoECAgQAw&usg=AOvVaw0xC9JU2RV4HvdviDhgbhoo) are some instructions for setting the tension on your model; there's no picture but it describes the location as being on top.